# Volley singleton is not working on repository in mvvm pattern

Tags: android, android-volley, android-mvvm

I am trying to integrate Volley singleton into an MVVM pattern. According to Android recommendations, a repository should be used to manage data from different sources (remote, local).

To make the work easier, I have created a singleton class for network requests through Volley, providing this class with a method for GET requests and another method for POST requests.

This is the singleton class:

```
public class VolleyService {

    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    Context mContext;

    public VolleyService(IResult resultCallback, Context context){
        mResultCallback = resultCallback;
        mContext = context;
    }


    public void postDataVolley(final String requestType, String url, JSONObject sendObj){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(url,sendObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType,response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType,error);
                }
            });

            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void getDataVolley(final String requestType, String url){
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObj = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("VolleyService", "RESPONSE:Volley requester iniRepo"+response.toString() );

                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifySuccess(requestType, response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("VolleyService", "ERROR:Volley requester iniRepo"+error.toString() );

                    if(mResultCallback != null)
                        mResultCallback.notifyError(requestType, error);
                }
            });

            queue.add(jsonObj);

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

I have also implemented an interface:

```
public interface IResult {
    public void notifySuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response);
    public void notifyError(String requestType, VolleyError error);
}
```

Then, as I understand, the data that comes from the network should be obtained in the repository. For this I have done the following:

1. Create an additional constructor in the repository class to have an application reference, to have the context, which is necessary for Volley requests. I don't know if it's the best way to do it.
2. Try to get the remote data using Volley's singleton class. This is what doesn't work.

As a test I have created a simple method, which I call from `loadProduct()`, but the Volley request does not occur and I don't know why.

This is my repository class:

```
public class DataRepository {

    private static DataRepository sInstance;

    private AppDatabase mDatabase;
    private MediatorLiveData<List<ProductEntity>> mObservableProducts;
    Application application;

    private DataRepository(final AppDatabase database) {
        mDatabase = database;
        mObservableProducts = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        mObservableProducts.addSource(mDatabase.productDao().loadAllProducts(),
                productEntities -> {
                    if (mDatabase.getDatabaseCreated().getValue() != null) {
                        mObservableProducts.postValue(productEntities);
                    }
                });
    }
    private DataRepository(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public static DataRepository getInstance(final AppDatabase database) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (DataRepository.class) {
                if (sInstance == null) {
                    sInstance = new DataRepository(database);
                }
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of products from the database and get notified when the data changes.
     */
    public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> getProducts() {
        return mObservableProducts;
    }

    public LiveData<ProductEntity> loadProduct(final int productId) {
        Log.d("fromRepo", "ok");
        //Only for test
        initVolleyCallback();
        return mDatabase.productDao().loadProduct(productId);
    }

    public LiveData<List<CommentEntity>> loadComments(final int productId) {
        return mDatabase.commentDao().loadComments(productId);
    }

    public LiveData<List<ProductEntity>> searchProducts(String query) {
        return mDatabase.productDao().searchAllProducts(query);
    }

    /*
       I created this method only for test
       It's not working here
    */
    public  String initVolleyCallback(){
        Log.d("VolleyFromRepo", "ok");
        IResult mResultCallback = null;
        VolleyService mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,application);
        mVolleyService.getDataVolley("GETCALL","myURLHere");
        return "ok";
    }

}
```

For test, i call `loadData()` from my Activity class and it's not working:

```
    LiveData<ProductEntity> liveData = getRepository().loadProduct(2);
    liveData.observe(this, m -> {
        Log.d(TAG, m.getDescription());
    });
```

I can see the log of `m.getDescription()`, i can see the log of `VolleyFromRepo`, but i can't see the data.

If I put the same method in the Activity it does work:

```
/*
   From activity it's working
   I can see the logs
*/
void initVolleyCallback(){
    IResult mResultCallback = null;
    mVolleyService = new VolleyService(mResultCallback,this);
    mVolleyService.getDataVolley("GETCALL","myURLHere");

}
```

What's wrong into my approach? Why the Volley call is not working into my repository class?

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://github.com/google/volley/issues/235

Comment: @IronMan thanks. I don't having any error, my issue is that the request from repository is not working. From the Activity the request works.

Comment: Empty value at MainActivity because, At the repository function loadProduct you return data from database but after volley success get data from server you dont insert to database